# How to cancel/discard a scroll function?

Tags: jquery

I've a function for window scroll like this:

```
function fixDiv() {
//scroll script goes here
}
$(window).scroll(fixDiv);
```

Now I want to cancel the function when the button is clicked

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
//cancel the fixDiv() function
// I have tried this:
fixDiv != fixDiv; // and changed/set variable for fixDiv() like var fixDiv = function(){}
});
```

But seems not working. What way can I cancel the function.

(please note: if again clicked on the button that should be functioning again)

---

please read the bounty description.

Comment: First of all, `fixDiv != fixDiv` wouldn't work because it *compares* `fixDiv` with itself and returns `false`.

Comment: yeah! I've tried this by setting false so that fixDiv would not function.

Comment: What about `$(window).off("scroll")` ?

Comment: `$(window).off("scroll", fixDiv )` or use namespaced event

Comment: if I use .off() function then this would not toggle the function as I needed to cancel and active the function on click and re-click

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like that:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LEef9/)

```
$('button').on('click', function () {
    this.off = !this.off;
    $(window)[this.off?'off':'on']("scroll", fixDiv )
});
```

**UPDATE**

Now if you want to override the function itself, you could use following code:

```
//using anonymous function as handler, code inside is processing on the fly
$('#anchorAnonymous').on('click',function(){
    fixDiv();
    //any other code, still be called even fixDiv() is overrided...
});
//click to override fixDiv() function
$('#btnoverride').on('click', function () {
    this.override = !this.override;
    //$.noop = function(){} -> do nothing
    fixDiv = this.override?$.noop:storedFixDiv;
});
//this is used to store fixDiv() function
window.storedFixDiv = fixDiv;
```

Beware, overriding the function won't override the handler if used as referenced method. Because jQuery will create a handler for each event stored in `$._data(elem,"events")`.
To illustrate it, see difference in jsfiddle:

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/LEef9/3/)

Comment: @C-link this is a simplified demo, it works as expected, click test, see alert, click button 'click' and no more alert when clicking test. Reclick button, then click handler rebound to anchor test, etc...

Comment: I'm not seeing the alert when clicked.

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward thx for providing more accurate demo ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff I'm here to help :-)

Comment: please have a look once to my bounty description.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of invalidate the function you can bind/unbind the event.

Code:

```
function fixDiv() {
    console.log('demo')
}
$(window).on('scroll', fixDiv);

$('button').on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("scroll")) {
        $(window).off('scroll', fixDiv);        
    } else {
        $(window).on('scroll', fixDiv);
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("scroll")
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/rqeW7/

Answer (score 0):

did you try this?

```
var fixDiv = function(){
  /*some code*/
}

$('button').on('click',function(){
   fixDiv = function(){};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define global variable on `document` object and toggle its value on button click.
Like:

```
document.scrollFlag = true;
function fixDiv() {
    if(document.scrollFlag) {
        console.log("called");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(fixDiv);
    $("#stopBtn").click(function() {
        document.scrollFlag = !document.scrollFlag;
    });
});
```